# How to determine the IOS version from within an Flex mobile app (AIR)

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air

I want to determine whether my Flex mobile app is running on a IOS device with IOS 7.

I need to find out because I want to lower the actionbar of the application if it is run on IOS 7 to provide room for the indicators (battery, wifi, etc.).

According to documentation the Flex Capabilities class does not provide me with an IOS version number.

The only option I can think of is to build a Native extension and query the version using IOS functions. But I do not really look forward to building that extension. Even less so because apparently you need a Mac with XCode to build the IOS part, and I don't own a Mac. A VM with OSX installed could be my last resort.

Maybe you know another option?

Comment: Have you got the latest version of Flex and Adobe AIR? They should position the app correctly for you.

Comment: No, I am using Flex 4.6, didn't know/find that this was fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex 4.12 actually introduced a way to fix this through CSS (4.12 introduced OS and OS version checks as well, which is awesome):

```
@media (application-dpi: 160) AND (os-platform:"IOS") AND (min-os-version: 7)
{
    Application {
         osStatusBarHeight: 20;
    }
}
```

But to answer your question, this function does the job:

```
public static function get iOSVersion():uint {
    var iosVersion:String = Capabilities.os.match( /([0-9]\.?){2,3}/ )[0];
    return Number( iosVersion.substr( 0, iosVersion.indexOf( "." ) ) );
}
```

I pulled that from my personal AS3 utility library. For sure, this will not work to get the Android version number and I am unsure if it will work for Mac or Windows. It will return the **major version number only** (minor versions are generally irrelevant). If you want to change that, just return `iosVersion` in the function instead of the second line.

Comment: Thanks! Now I face the task of migrating to Apache Flex.

Comment: Ah, this works in Flex 4.6 as well, no need to migrate (yet).

Comment: The top part was implemented in Flex 4.12 (`os-platform`, `min-os-version`, and `osStatusBarHeight` all were), so you would absolutely have to upgrade to use it (upgrading should be painless, honestly). The second part has been in AIR for as long as I can remember. You're just parsing the OS string, which on iOS includes the version number. No need for Flex at all.